# r - apply single condition on multiple columns

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with many columns and getting the following summary is lots of manual work. In the sample dataset it is required to calculate the sum of the `value` column three times only for the observations where the con columns are "TRUE" separately for each.

```
# sample dataset
df <- data.frame(
  value = c(1:20),
  con1 = c("TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE"),
  con2 = c("FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE"),
  con3 = c("FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE"))
```

Manually the process can be done like this:

```
df %>% group_by(con1) %>% summarise(value = sum(value))
```

In this case the sum of the `value` column for the observations only when the corresponding value in the `con1` column is "TRUE", is 70.

The end dataframe should look like this:

```
data.frame(con1 = 70, con2 = 63, con3 = 57)
```

Comment: You should probably use R's built-in TRUE/FALSE instead of reinventing that wheel with "TRUE"/"FALSE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `summarise_at` to summarize *con* columns, and for each column, apply it as logical filter to *value* column and sum it up:

```
df %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with('con')), funs(sum(value[as.logical(.)])))

#  con1 con2 con3
#1   70   63   57
```